# How to get border-radius to produce an elliptical radius up top and square corners at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I'd like a CSS div with an arched top and a square (or slightly rounded corners) bottom.

Here's my CSS:

```
  #oval {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 80px/20px 5px;
  }
```

I also tried `80px/20px 80px/20px 5px 5px` with no luck, and a bunch of other combinations. I've been testing in Firefox.

Any help would rock!

Comment: what's wrong with `border-top-radius`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
border-radius: 80px 80px 5px 5px / 20px 20px 5px 5px;
```

Comment: Yep, I figured out the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try building out each corner separately like this

```
  .oval {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;

border-top-left-radius:200px;
border-top-right-radius:200px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0;
border-bottom-left-radius:0;

    //border-radius: 80px/20px 5px;
  }
```

Comment: I'm interested in an oval top, I just got it, updating with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the rule:         `border-radius: 85% 85% 5px 5px / 15% 15% 5px 5px;`

Apparently, you specify all the horizontal radii for four corners, then all the vertical radii